# Chernoff faces extended in R

Tags: r, plot

The `aplpack` library contains the possibility to plot beautiful Chernoff faces with `faces`. `symbols` and `TeachingDemos` also offer the possibility to plot variations of these faces. But none of them allows to plot more than 15 dimensions (`symbols` allows two more dimensions for colours, but they are defined in an inconvenient way so that some faces turn out to be completely black, hiding other parts of the face). Is there a way in `R` (perhaps with another library) to plot more dimensions, e.g. by adding a body with limbs of different lengths or by using colours to visualise some of the dimensions? Maybe I've overseen something and the colours in `aplpack` can be mapped to variables as well?

Comment: interesting question, although it's also sort of hard to imagine a viewer actually being able to comprehend a data display of more than 15 dimensions ...

Comment: @BenBolker That's actually the reason I want to use Chernoff faces at all: It's almost impossible to visualise 20 or 30 dimensions in a quantitative way and still to be able to compare these dimensions between groups. With Chernoff faces, you can see at one glance if there are any large differences, and if so, which variables/dimensions differ at most. Once you're there, you can pick these variables out of the mass and look closer at them in a more quantitative way.

Answer (score 1):

The TeachingDemos package also has the `ms.face` function that works with the `my.symbols` function to create a scatterplot with the Chernoff Face as the symbol.  This gives the original 15 values of the face, plus an x-coordinate and a y-coordinate; with `my.symbols` you can also specify a color (for the overall face, not individual features) and an overall size based on variables.  That gives 19 dimensions, you could also vary the line width and style, but that will probably distort the plot more than help.

With that many dimensions I would probably go more for the star plots (`symbols` function) with the variables ordered based on a clustering procedure, or use some type of dimension reduction tool (principal components, grand tour, etc.)